# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4 is autosaving my files every 1 second

Tags: intellij-idea, save, settings

I know one great feature of Intellij IDEA is saving your work automatically. But I have a Bug with that feature. No matter what setting I choose if I disable `Save files automatically if application is idle for N seconds` and `Save files on frame deactivation` or if i enter 15s idle time before autosaving my files get saved instantly when editing them.

The annoying on this bug is, that I let cut all tailing white-spaces when saving a file. So when i edit a file all indention of the new line gets removed cause of autosaving.

So my Question are there anywhere else options to set autosaving?

EDIT: After switching to an other project I didn't recognized this behavior. So there must definitely some setting in the Project-setting which overrides the Option `Save files automatically if application is idle for N seconds`.

Comment: I am not sure about auto save but you can enable _Always keep trailing spaces on caret line_ (in Settings/Editor/General) in which case auto save will not strip the trailing spaces on the line you are currently on.

Comment: Report that bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: @Meo thanks for that link I created an Issue also there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168991

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you have a [File Watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html#d405088e375) with the **Immediate file synchronization** option enabled.

Another possible case is the **Build project automatically** [option enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7HH2.png). This will save and compile the changes on the fly to report any errors from the compiler and to ensure fast running so that you don't have to wait for the compilation before run.

There is an open issue for always autosaving `pom.xml` files. If it's the case, vote for it:

- [IDEA-63462](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63462) Autosave should be turned off / massively delayed for pom.xml files